# Creating queue of notifications upon launch on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

Noob Android developer here. I'm growing familiar with `NotificationManager` and `AlarmManager`, however I'm struggling to grasp how I would implement this.

Basically it would go like this:

```
1. Open app at 7am
2. Create queue of notifications from 8am-5pm
3. Each notification would appear every hour on the hour from 8am-5pm, even if the app is closed.
```

Can `AlarmManager` be used for this? Or is there something else?

Comment: You can totally use `AlarmManager` in your case. Confidently do it and if there are any difficulties, please ask questions for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AlarmManager` could do this, code could refer to [this link](https://github.com/ajitsing/AlarmManagerAndReceiver).

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't matter for you to show notifications at the exact time, you can use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=CjwKCAjwmK6IBhBqEiwAocMc8g6ZVOXNfhI4ZpwG4TBfi_KnEKs7EBG_aP-2AxsGbZR30XqkQgXOuRoC4YIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) it consumes less battery. However, it will show your notifications in a range of times, for instance, if you set it at 5 am it might show a notification at 5:40. If you want the exact time use AlarmManager with full-screen intent notification.